# AHK How to fix KeyPress is not breaking the loop

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

The script is intended to break the loop on XButton1, but fails.

I am a newbie in AHK scripting and a really simple script I made is not working as intended. I googled it and it works on everyone.

```
ended = false

XButton1::
ended = true
return

$XButton2::
ended = false
Loop
{
    if (ended = true)
    {
        break
    }
    MouseClick left
    Sleep 10
}
return
```

It was supposed to click infinitely until Mouse4 (XButton1) is pressed. But it does not stop when I click it.

I also checked other StackOverflow posts and nothing solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses [legacy-syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#legacy-syntax) which was a major headache for me (and I believe many others) when I was starting with AHK.

To make your code work change:

`if (ended = true)`
to
`if (ended = "true")`

Consider switching to `:=` ([SetExpression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm)) instead of `=`

For example:

`ended = false`
should become
`ended := false`